# How we he handle requests priority in express/nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, request, database

We all know that NodeJs can handle way more requests than normal Java server,
but how does one maintain a FIFO kind of structure for incoming requests?

Lets say a flash sale, where thousands of requests bombard in short amount of time to buy something which is of limited quantity??

How do we decide which request gets to get the product first and change the status of the product from `available` to `sold out` (just an example)?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In node.js, only one request actually runs at a time (the Javascript interpreter is single threaded) until you hit some sort of async operation in native code and then another request gets to start running while the other one is waiting for I/O.  If there is some limited resource that all the requests are after, it is just a race to see which request gets far enough through your code to get the resource.  If you cluster your server for added scalability, then each cluster runs one Javascript thread.

If you made each incoming request wait in a queue until all other requests that came before it were completely done (something that could be done), then you'd seriously wreck the scalability of your node.js server and most of the time it would be sitting idle waiting for some I/O operation to be done so it seems unlikely that that is the correct design.

> Lets say a flash sale, where thousands of requests bombard in short
>   amount of time to buy something which is of limited quantity??
>
> How do we decide which request gets to get the product first and
>   change the status of the product from available to sold out (just an
>   example)?

The usual scheme here is to just let the first request that gets through to claim the resource have it (even though multiple resources may be running at the same time).  Whether this is always the request that first arrived at your server or not is not going to be known, but it will be close and the user community is unlikely to know if it happened to be off by a few milliseconds just due to the variance in processing speed of two requests.

You will have to make sure your code that accesses shared resources (like databases) is safe for concurrency and does not make any troublesome assumptions about shared data.

Comment: i agree with your point, but what if a request invokes a async method and before this function could finish execution, there are 10 other async methods invoked by 10 other requests. (lets assume there are only 5 products left)
the first request still hasn't updated the available products on the db from 5 to 4, at this time all other requests see 5 available products, where as there are only 4 now(1st request get the first product). How do we handle this? and what happens if the number of requests is multiplied by say 100x?

Comment: @syedfaizan - What you're describing is a design challenge for concurrent requests.  There's no generic solution.  It depends upon a lot of things, including what types of shared data manipulations you're doing and what behavioral requirements there are.  We'd have to see all the relevant code and understand your data and data model and your business problem/application to begin to help at any level of detail.

Comment: i was asked this question during an interview, and he asked what is your approach to solving this problem? i had no idea of this problem, but wanted to know the answer , google didn't help (i didnt know what this problem is called) so i just posted here, i am sorry i didn't explain this to you before, just thought it might help in the future

Comment: @syedfaizan - Did this answer your question?  If so, please indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  If not, then please explain what you still need help with.